# C# interop Excel: is possible to set NumberFormat like Value2?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to set NumberFormat in Excel with C# for quite big Range. Its big table and make it cell by cell consume too much time.

I tried it similar like setting Value2 for range:

```
 rng = ws.get_Range("H" + 2, "S" + 2);
 rng.NumberFormat = numberFormat;
```

Where numberFormat is array of objects with formatting strings (like "0.00", "0.0000", ...)
Looks like this will not work because it looks to me, that NumberFormat is just one property for whole Range.

Do you have any idea how to make it fast, not cell by cell approach?
Thank you!

Comment: What library are you using for interacting with Excel?

Comment: Wild stab: Much of interop is based on Excel UI actions.  The only way to do something like that in the UI is to "Paste Special: Formats".  Is there something similar in the interop object model?

Comment: @Flydog57 yes, you are probably right. I will use pasteSpecial function from C# as it mentioned here:
[link here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542864/copy-format-from-one-row-to-another-using-c-sharp)
Dissadvantage is, at least one i must fill formats data cell by cell. Another one, there must be same patterns of data on whose I would like to apply my pasteSpecial function. Probably as you said, there is no more easy way :) Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this to the cells in a single row?  Or, are you doing it to the cells in many rows?  If the latter, do the format-setting column by column, rather than row by row.

Comment: @HagashenNaidu I do not use any custom library.

Comment: @Flydog57 Why, is it fastest way?

Comment: I have no idea, but the formats in a single column are likely the same.  As a result, your `rng.NumberFormat = numberFormat;` statement will likely work if `rng` is a column.  Caveat, I have *never* done Excel interop.  A few macros, lots of OpenXml, but no interop

Comment: You could also try creating a style and then applying that instead which maybe be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to know you guys I resolved this by solution that was already placed here (shame on me)

[How to specify format for individual cells with Excel.Range.set_Value()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315614/4461586)

I just slightly modified solution of Drew Shafer (thanx man).
based on my research it is best possible solution for excel via interop.

Besides of the limitation of Excel, His solution is really elegant.